# I need to get column names from a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetBillOfMaterials]
    @StartProductID [int],
    @CheckDate [datetime]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Use recursive query to generate a multi-level Bill of Material (i.e. all level 1 
    -- components of a level 0 assembly, all level 2 components of a level 1 assembly)
    -- The CheckDate eliminates any components that are no longer used in the product on this date.
    WITH [BOM_cte]([ProductAssemblyID], [ComponentID], [ComponentDesc], [PerAssemblyQty], [StandardCost], [ListPrice], [BOMLevel], [RecursionLevel]) -- CTE name and columns
    AS (
        SELECT b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[ComponentID], p.[Name], b.[PerAssemblyQty], p.[StandardCost], p.[ListPrice], b.[BOMLevel], 0 -- Get the initial list of components for the bike assembly
        FROM [Production].[BillOfMaterials] b
            INNER JOIN [Production].[Product] p 
            ON b.[ComponentID] = p.[ProductID] 
        WHERE b.[ProductAssemblyID] = @StartProductID 
            AND @CheckDate >= b.[StartDate] 
            AND @CheckDate <= ISNULL(b.[EndDate], @CheckDate)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[ComponentID], p.[Name], b.[PerAssemblyQty], p.[StandardCost], p.[ListPrice], b.[BOMLevel], [RecursionLevel] + 1 -- Join recursive member to anchor
        FROM [BOM_cte] cte
            INNER JOIN [Production].[BillOfMaterials] b 
            ON b.[ProductAssemblyID] = cte.[ComponentID]
            INNER JOIN [Production].[Product] p 
            ON b.[ComponentID] = p.[ProductID] 
        WHERE @CheckDate >= b.[StartDate] 
            AND @CheckDate <= ISNULL(b.[EndDate], @CheckDate)
        )
    -- Outer select from the CTE
    SELECT 
        b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[ComponentID], b.[ComponentDesc], 
        SUM(b.[PerAssemblyQty]) AS [TotalQuantity], b.[StandardCost], 
        b.[ListPrice], b.[BOMLevel], b.[RecursionLevel]
    FROM 
        [BOM_cte] b
    GROUP BY 
        b.[ComponentID], b.[ComponentDesc], b.[ProductAssemblyID], 
        b.[BOMLevel], b.[RecursionLevel], b.[StandardCost], b.[ListPrice]
    ORDER BY 
        b.[BOMLevel], b.[ProductAssemblyID], b.[ComponentID]
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25) 
END;
```

Is there a way I can get all the columns names used in a SQL Server stored procedure? I need the column names used in the clauses such as select, where, group by, order by, etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `FMTONLY` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173839.aspx

Comment: @IvanStarostin - Good to know

Comment: @IvanStarostin - But it will not help OP. This will bring the columns present  only in `SELECT` list. OP wants column used in `where,group by,order by,etc`

Comment: @Prdp yeah, looks like he wants all dependencies.

Comment: Yes @Prdp I want all the column names used in the clauses such as select,where,group by,order by.

Comment: @mehmoodshah - I don't think it is possible. You can search for a column used inside a procedure but listing it based on the usage is not possible I think

Comment: You'd have to get the stored procedure T-SQL source code (pretty easy), and then start parsing it yourself (rather tricky) ....

Comment: I need it automated as I need to scan multiple procedures from database

Comment: @mehmoodshah, you can get part of the way there with sp_describe_first_result_set (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) but will need a parser to analyze clauses beyond `SELECT`.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks! I can get the column names used in select clause. But I need all the dependent columns used in the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any query which can give you exactly all the columns used in a stored procedure. There is one way you can do it using the SSMS.

- Go to Object Explorer > Databases > YourDatabase > Programmability > Stored Procedures
- Right Click on YourProcedure > View Dependencies
- Select second option in Radio Button list (Objects on which [YourProcedure] depends

You will get a tree view of all the tables, tables links and columns a procedure is dependent upon.

Let me know if this was what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, But I need the column names, above way did'nt take me anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure you tried correctly? This way does give you the names of the columns a SQL Stored Procedure is dependent upon.

Comment: I also tried this with stored procedured that did a simple "Select A,B,C from dbo.MyTable",  and only "MyTable" showed up, not A, B, C.

Comment: There must be a + sign before the table name. It's to expand the tree view I was talking about.

Comment: Yes @ChaosLegion I can see that but expanding it still does not give the column names.